# How to use gem whenever on google cloud?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, cron, gcloud

I have a problem with running a hema whenever on gcloud.

more precisely, with the execution of the command `whenever --update-crontab`

but I'm also not sure whether cron is installed and I do not understand how to check this. Can anyone come across?

I'm using gitlab CI for deploy.
And this gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/varuno/photo-booth-admin

stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
  - export PATH="/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - bundle install
    - cp ./config/database.sample.yml ./config/database.yml
    - echo $MASTER_KEY > ./config/master.key
    - echo $DEPLOY_KEY_FILE > ./config/google-key.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ./config/google-key.json
    - gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION
    - gcloud info
    - gcloud app deploy --quiet --stop-previous-version --promote --version=photo-booth
    - gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding photo-booth-201515 --member=serviceAccount:22202411108@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/editor
    - bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate
    # - bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use the `whenever` gem on GAE, since GAE doesn't use the *nix style `cron` service.

The GAE cron service is really just a generator of `GET` requests to certain configured URLs according to a configured schedule. Your app handlers for those URLs are the ones actually executing the jobs. See [Scheduling Jobs with cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)

To use the GAE cron service you need to create a [`cron.yaml` configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#about) inside your app and deploy it to GAE. Of course, your app code should include the corresponding URL handlers.

To deploy the `cron.yaml` file from your CI system you'd need to add this command to your `gitlab-ci.yml`, probably right after the existing `gcloud app deploy ...` command (see [Uploading cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#uploading_cron_jobs)):

```
gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```